# 2 Python 3 Async Clients Simultaneously (discord.py + aiohttp.web)

Tags: python-3.5, python-3.6, discord, aiohttp

I have a discord.py bot and I'd like to make it possible to activate a function within the discord bot by sending a GET request to the server.

I found this code elsewhere, but it doesn't work. No errors, but it still runs the clients one after the other.

```
def runInParallel(*fns):
  proc = []
  for fn in fns:
    p = Process(target=fn)
    p.start()
    proc.append(p)
  for p in proc:
    p.join()
```

How can I have an aiohttp server running without shutting down the discord server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution of sorts, I had to use an async web server, namely the poorly documented Kyoukai - http://kyoukai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I can now silmeoutaneously interface with the Discord API and host a simple web server!

Answer (score 0):

you can run aiohttp along with any library that works with asyncio.
or you can start aiohttp in separate thread.

Comment: Ok, could you give me links to documentation or code examples? Starting the async processes hasn't worked for me as the command that starts each of the two asyncio libraries is blocking code.

Comment: there is no specific documentation how to run aiohttp in separate thread, but may try to search how to run asyncio event loop in separate thread.

in general, code may look something like this"

def start_web():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    web = aiohttp.web.Application()

    aiohttp.web.run_app(app, loop=lop)


threading.Thread(start_web).run